# Django REST Framework with viewset-router queryset filter

Tags: python, django, rest, view, django-queryset

I want to do data filtering in a api response. Ie make such addresses

```
/api/v1//CoinCost/full?coin_id=coin_name&dateStart=2020-02-06T00:00:00&dateEnd=2020-02-08T00:00:00
```

now i have this url

```
/api/v1/CoinCost/
```

And no filtering.

My code:

**views.py**

```
class CoinCostViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):

    def list(self, request):
        queryset = Coins.objects.all()
        serializer = CoinSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

**urls.py**

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register('CoinCost', CoinCostViewSet, basename='Coins')

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
    ]
```

**serializers.py**

```
class CoinCostsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    fields = ('coin_id', 'crr', 'volume', 'reserve', 'price', 'timestamp')
    model = CoinCost
```

**models.py**

```
class CoinCost(models.Model):
coin_id = models.ForeignKey(Coins, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
crr = models.CharField(max_length=3)
volume = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=4)
reserve = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=4)
price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=4)
timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
```

Please help make the necessary filtering. To get filtering url. I’ve been sitting for two days, I don’t understand.I studied a lot of documentation and tried different methods for a week now. But didn’t help . Thanks!

Comment: Why are you redefining `list` in your VIewSet?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using [`django_filters`](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/rest_framework.html). You'll need to go through the installation and setup part. But your code should look as follows. The filtering fields may be different than what you want. If that's a hard requirement, you can look at the documentation to see how to change names of the parameters.

I've also fixed the model and serializer for the `CoinCostViewSet` to be related to `CoinCost` rather than `Coins`.

```
from django_filters import rest_framework as filters

class CoinCostFilterSet(filters.FilterSet)
    class Meta:
        model = CoinCost
        fields = {
            'coin_id': ['exact'],
            'timestamp': ['gt', 'lt'],
        }

class CoinCostViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    queryset = CoinCost.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CoinCostsSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filterset_class = CoinCostFilterSet
```

Comment: Hello! schillingt! Thanks !Your code for view.py, right? I try, but so far it doesn’t work, swears that the page was not found, invalid URL. Hm... I read the documentation and tried everything, but nothing works. Although I configured and installed clean django with the necessary modules.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can understan you wanted to get paramaters passed by the url, and you wanted filter. I did not quite understand about your Model, but you can do filtering with Model.objects.filter() and serialize it then return it as a JSON data. I passed the filtering part and just wrote about getting query params from url.

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework import status


class CoinApiView(APIView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        query_params = request.query_params
        coin_id = query_params.get('coin_id', None)
        date_start = query_params.get('dateStart', None)
        date_end = query_params.get('dateEnd', None)

        # if you need date_obj from string
        # date_obj = datetime.fromisoformat(date_start)
        print(coin_id)
        print(date_start)
        print(date_end)
        # In Response you can return anyting For ex: Response({'coins': ['Coin1', 'Coin2', ..], status=status.HTTP_200_OK})
        return Response(status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Comment: I am sharing a link which includes a little sample of searching. Just to explain steps:
https://github.com/abdukhashimov/djangosearchviaurlparams/blob/master/search-view-sample.py